# jQuery not loading?

Tags: jquery, html

Feel free to yell abuse at me if I'm being stupid here, but I'm getting confused. It seems like everything should work fine :/ I've triple checked the file locations and everything is fine

I have this in the head:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Website</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
</head>
```

I have a list of links like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
   <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

And in functions.js I have this...

```
console.log('WTF.. THIS LOGS IN THE CONSOLE!?!?!?!');

// debugging purposes
alert($('a').attr('href'));

$('.menu li a').click(function(e){
    alert('hey');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I get an alert saying 'undefined' and when I click on a link, default actions is prevented and I don't get an alert...

The conclusion I've come to is there was a problem somewhere with the jQuery... but I just can't find whats going on here

Comment: have you surrounded your jquery-calls by `$(document).ready(function() { /* your code */ });` or `$(function() { /* your code */ });`??

Comment: Which browser do you use? I recommend a plugin like firebug (for firefox) to detect such errors (broken links, script errors etc...)

Comment: I'm such an idiot! I forgot something this basic

Comment: may need a live code sample, can you put something up at jsfiddle.net? otherwise, it is possible that your document is not loaded before you start actioning on your DOM elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have to wrap your code within a document.ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('WTF.. THIS LOGS IN THE CONSOLE!?!?!?!');

    // debugging purposes
    alert($('a').attr('href'));

    $('.menu li a').click(function(e){
        alert('hey');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Keep in mind Javascript is executed as soon as it appears in a page, your `<a>` elements do not exist yet when your script executes. Using the "ready" event, you ensure your DOM is fully available when your code runs.

You could also add the reference to your functions.js file at the end of the body, before `</body>` tag.

Comment: yeah as a convention, if you're likely to forget using :ready, you should be putting your scripts at the end of the body tag, agreed.

Comment: You can even simply get rid of the document.ready this way actually.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(function(){
    //....Your code of java script must be
});
```

try this,it will run..

Comment: Unformatted code is unreadable. You'd rather add a few explanation words.

Answer (score 3):

You tried wrapping it all in a `$(document).ready()` to ensure the dom has loaded?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('WTF.. THIS LOGS IN THE CONSOLE!?!?!?!');

    // debugging purposes
    alert($('a').attr('href'));

    $('.menu li a').click(function(e){
        alert('hey');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

That should work for you. (Shortcut for `$(document).ready(function() {});` is `$(function() {});`

Comment: I'm such an idiot! I forgot something this basic... I don't use jQuery very often

Answer (score 2):

If the code you pasted is the exact content of your functions.js file then you'll have a problem. Your code is executing before the document is ready. Put your initialization code in a function inside functions.js and then call that function when the document is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // now call your init function
    myInitCode();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script element appears in the head and does nothing to delay execution of the code (e.g. by putting it in a function and using `document.ready`).

Your links appear in the body, which is after the head, so they do not exist when the code runs.

Answer (score -3):

have you tried to return false in the click event? like following?

```
$('.menu li a').click(function(e){
    alert('hey');
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```