# jQuery not executing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This seems a bit like a simplistic question but it keeps bothering me and I can't solve it. I am currently trying to make a `div` be replaced by `iframe` on click of a button. Despite the simplistic nature of this issue and me already having the right answer, I cannot manage to run it for some reason.

Firstly it was giving me:

> $ not defined

Which I know it's an issue regarding the jQuery library not being correctly inserted in the html file. Afterwards I reshuffled my libraries and it still doesn't execute properly.

I've ready most of the previous topics where jQuery is not working with all the possible solutions suggested. I am quite aware of the two previous questions one with 33 and the other with 26 answers.

I've even tried downloading jQuery to a file and utilizing it localy but it still doesn't run. Can you help me figure out how to fix this.

jQuery code:

```
 $('.playbutton,img').click(function(){
            var video = '<div class="video-container"><iframe src="'+ $('img').attr('data-video') +'"></iframe></div>';
            $('.video').hide();
         $('.tube').html(video);
         $('.close').show();
        });
 $('.close').click(function(){
            $('.video').show();
       $('.tube').empty();
     $('.close').hide();
        });
```

HTML code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>

          <img src ="img/beme.png" class ="logo">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        </div>

        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
          </form>
        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

<div class ="banner">
    <div class ="row" id ="mid-row">
            <img src ="img/background.png" id ="big-image">
            <img src ="img/play-button.png" id ="play">
    </div>



<div class="video">
<div class="playbutton">Play</div>    
<img src="http://cdn0.sbnation.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/5372321/battlefield3-screen-12.0_cinema_640.0.jpeg" data-video="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/U8HVQXkeU8U?&autoplay=1&rel=0&fs=0&showinfo=0&autohide=3&modestbranding=1">
    </div>
    <div class="tube"></div>
    <div class="close">Close X</div>

</div>
```

How my libraries are inserted:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<!-- Angular and Bootstrap files -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Angular and Bootstrap Files -->

<!-- Personal CSS file -->
<link rel ="stylesheet" href ="css/style.css">
<!-- Personal CSs file -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

I am basically trying to recreate this JSFiddle but with no luck:http://jsfiddle.net/ANRHT/6/

Comment: Open your browser console and check your Network tab. Check if your jquery-x.js is successfully loaded.

Comment: They are added before the script, I just showed them last...

Comment: Make sure your jquery path is correct. View source on the page and find where the jquery script line is, click on it and see if it loads the jquery file

Comment: It loads jquery when I link it remotely and when I have the file locally.

Comment: ok then you need to paste more complete code, from where the jquery file is called, to your scripts, you can remove the current stuff since your complete code will have them anyway. If everything is called correctly then you shouldn't have this issue of `$ not defined`

Comment: @ZombieChowder are you tried putting your script in $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: @Huangism , here is a screenshot of the output:

https://postimg.org/image/unfaun307/

Comment: @ZombieChowder not exactly what I wanted but at least we know jquery is loaded. Your js, where is it at on the page? Need to see more complete code

Comment: @Huangism 
 
yes, my jquery code is located on the page inside a <script> tag. I've tried specifying the type of the tag as well but still no luck

Comment: @ZombieChowder see Rahul in previous comment. If you cannot paste more complete code then there isn't much we can do

Comment: @Huangism Rahul's comment actually worked, the only problem that remains is why I cannot access the file. It just gives me "file not found" even though I am loading from youtube.

Comment: @ZombieChowder try to debug the URL/inspect the output code. If you can't figure it out then you should post another question on it. But since you did not have document ready, you should probably read other post with similar issue more carefully. This question can be closed as duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery not loading?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078224/jquery-not-loading)

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('.playbutton,img').click(function(){
                var video = '<div class="video-container"><iframe src="'+ $('img').attr('data-video') +'"></iframe></div>';
                $('.video').hide();
             $('.tube').html(video);
             $('.close').show();
            });
     $('.close').click(function(){
                $('.video').show();
           $('.tube').empty();
         $('.close').hide();
            });
```

```css
@import url(http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>

          <img src ="img/beme.png" class ="logo">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        </div>

        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
          </form>
        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

<div class ="banner">
    <div class ="row" id ="mid-row">
            <img src ="img/background.png" id ="big-image">
            <img src ="img/play-button.png" id ="play">
    </div>



<div class="video">
<div class="playbutton">Play</div>    
<img src="http://cdn0.sbnation.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/5372321/battlefield3-screen-12.0_cinema_640.0.jpeg" data-video="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/U8HVQXkeU8U?&autoplay=1&rel=0&fs=0&showinfo=0&autohide=3&modestbranding=1">
    </div>
    <div class="tube"></div>
    <div class="close">Close X</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Answers should provide a bit of context, rather than a game of spot-the-difference.